# How to plot time as x axis in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am trying to plot a data-frame in pandas. The csv file I am using is:

```
Time,Total cpu%,Used mem(k),Cache mem(k),Net mem Used%,Total mem Used%,Swap mem(%),process1 cpu%,process1 mem%,
4:19:25,12.5,885324,1249960,38.38,38.38,0,6.2,34.7
4:19:28,0.4,885460,1249804,38.39,38.39,0,5.3,34.7
4:19:31,1.8,885700,1249528,38.4,38.4,0,5,34.7
4:19:34,0.7,885700,1249528,38.4,38.4,0,5.3,34.7
4:19:37,0.4,885708,1249528,38.4,38.4,0,5.3,34.7
4:19:40,2.1,885704,1249528,38.4,38.4,0,5.3,34.7
4:19:43,0.4,885704,1249528,38.4,38.4,0,5,34.7
4:19:47,0.7,885700,1249528,38.4,38.4,0,5.3,34.7
4:19:50,13.8,885704,1249528,38.4,38.4,0,16,34.7
```

My code so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('sample_csv.csv')

# select only cpu columns
cpu_columns = ['Total cpu%', 'process1 cpu%']

# dataframe from cpu columns
df1 = df[cpu_columns]
```

I want to plot this data-frame with all the time values on X-axis.
So I created a list from values in "Time" column and set it as x_axis value as follows:

```
x_axis = df["Time"].values

# plot dataframe
df1.plot(x=df["Time"])
plt.show()
```

Following is the graph I could get so far:
[image: cpu usage graph]

So the label of X-axis is shown as "Time". How can I show the time values in "Time" column on X-axis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that your issue might be to do with the way your times are stored. If they are of `time` or `datetime` dtypes then the following should work nicely for you.

Set Time as the index and simply call plot. Pandas sets the index as the x-axis by default.

```
df.Time = df.Time.dt.time
df.set_index('Time').plot()
```

However, by the looks of your code, they are not. We can pass these as datetimes first, and then convert them to times (if needed). This can be done using `pd.to_datetime` as follows,

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time).dt.time
df.set_index('Time').plot()
```

**Note**: This will default to using today's date to add to the datetime. However this is then dropped when converting to a Time dtype.

Answer (score 6):

You can do so:

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.plot(x="Time", y=["Total cpu%", "process1 cpu%"])
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to show maximum if not all the x-axis labels? Clearly in above graph only a few Time values are shown.

Comment: What do you mean with maximum?

Comment: The number of x-ticks is very less. Is it possible to show more x-ticks? And is there a limit of number of x-ticks that can be displayed on a graph.?

Comment: `FutureWarning: Passing timedelta64-dtype data is deprecated, will raise a TypeError in a future version`