# Time not displaying when reading CSV file for graph (Pandas/MatPlotLib)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I'm currently reading in a CSV file using pandas and displaying a graph using the MatPlotLib.

On the graph on the axis the time isn't displaying. The graph is right in terms of the data but the time stamps won't display on the graph.

I've been using Excel to create the CSV files and have the time on Excel cells as the Time format.

Just wondering if I need to convert the time data before plotting the graph?

EDIT: Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', index_col = 0)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

(Very simple but works for reading the CSV file, the CSV file has 3 columns: First is Time and 2 others for plotting the graph)

Comment: Yes, try to convert to `date` before. Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556953/how-to-plot-time-as-x-axis-in-pandas/51557661#51557661

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately none of those methods worked in displaying the time for me.

Comment: Can you post your df?

Comment: See [mcve] for what is required to get help with such a problem.

Comment: I have the code typed out above in the question now